# Find the key in an object which contains a particular value in an array

Tags: javascript

I need to find the key(type:array) which contains a specific string. The actual data would look like as provided below

I tried to inverse the particular object with _.invert(). But doesnt make sense as it would convert the entire array to a string

```
{
  "key1": ['asd','yrt','uyt'],
  "key2": ['nbm','inb','oiu']
}
```

The response desired is that with we can fetch the key_name if an array element is provided.
ie if the input is lets 'asd' we need to be able to say that the key was key1

Comment: In order to help you please share what you have tried so we can see where you are stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the keys and find the element with includes.

```js
const
    find = (object, value) => Object.keys(object).find(k => object[k].includes(value)),
    object = { key1: ['asd','yrt','uyt'], key2: ['nbm','inb','oiu'] },
    key = find(object, 'asd');
    
console.log(key);
```

Answer (score 1):

How often are you going to do this? If only once, then:

```
data = {
 "key1": ['asd','yrt','uyt'],
 "key2": ['nbm','inb','oiu']
}
needle = 'oiu'
magicKey = Object.keys(data).filter(key => data[key].includes(needle))
```

Otherwise you're going to want to make a new dictionary that has your possible needles as keys!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const obj = { key1: ['asd','yrt','uyt'], key2: ['nbm','inb','oiu']}

const keyResult = Object.entries(obj).find(element => element[1].includes('asd'))

console.log(keyResult[0] || 'not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

It might look like this:

```
let elementToFind = "asd";
let object = {
  "key1": ['asd','yrt','uyt'],
  "key2": ['nbm','inb','oiu']
}

let output;

for(let key in object) { // iterate over every key in object
    if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // check if we don't try to access one of object's prototype fields etc.
        if(object[key].includes(elementToFind)) { 
            // check if object[key] which is array, contains element we look for
            // if so, break the loop to prevent it from further searching
            output = key;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let search = 'asd'
let obj = {
   "key1": ['asd','yrt','uyt'],
  "key2": ['nbm','inb','oiu']
}
Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key].indexOf(search) > -1)

If there can be multiple such keys use filter instead of find.
```

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to iterate over the key/value produced from `Object.entries`, and return the key where the string is found in the value (array).

```js
const obj = {
  key1: ['asd','yrt','uyt'],
  key2: ['nbm','inb','oiu']
}

function getKey(obj, str) {
  for (let [key, arr] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (arr.includes(str)) return key;
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(getKey(obj, 'inb'));
console.log(getKey(obj, 'asd'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that recursively returns the path...

```js
const hasKey = (key, data) => ({}).hasOwnProperty.call(data, key);
const typeOf = value => ({}).toString.call(value).replace(/\[object (\w+)]/, '$1');
const isLeaf = value => ['String', 'Boolean', 'Null', 'Undefined', 'Number', 'Date', 'Function'].includes(typeOf(value));

const needle = 'asd';
const haystack = {
  "key1": ['asd1','yrt','uyt'],
  "key2": ['nbm','inb','oiu'],
  key3: {
    key4: ['asd'],
  }
};

const find = (needle, haystack, path = []) => {
  if (isLeaf(haystack)) {
    return needle === haystack && path;
  }
  
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(haystack)) {
    const result = find(needle, value, path.concat(key));

  if (result) { return result; }
  }
};


console.log('find', find(needle, haystack));
```